# javascript not creating div

Tags: javascript, html

For the past two hours I have been trying to generate a `div` with certain properties. However, each time I try, nothing happens. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
function roundDivGenerator()
{

var roundDiv = document.createElement("div");

  roundDiv.id = "roundDiv" + gauballTracker;
  roundDiv.class = "roundDivClass";
  roundDiv.innerHtml = divTracker;
  document.getElementByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(roundDiv);

  var roundDivCss = document.getElementByClassName('roundDivClass').style;

    roundDivCss.height = "44px";
    roundDivCss.width = "44px";
    roundDivCss.backgroundColor = "#8ed066";
    roundDivCss.border = "#b0f2e6 3px solid";
    roundDivCss.borderRadius = "22px";

    roundDivTracker++;
}
round_Div_Generator();
```

Comment: Check console for errors...

Comment: 1) `.class` should be `.className`.

Comment: 2) `.getElementByTagName` should be `.getElementsByTagName` (notice the `s`).

Comment: 3) `.getElementByClassName` should be `.getElementsByClassName` (notice the `s`).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/emrczcc1/1/

Comment: 4) `var roundDivCss = document.getElementByClassName('roundDivClass').style` should be `var roundDivCss = roundDiv.style`. As `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTML collection (array-like object).

Comment: 5) The function name is `roundDivGenerator` not `round_Div_Generator`.

Comment: 6) This whole line `document.getElementByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(roundDiv);` can be shorted to `document.body.appendChild(roundDiv);`

Comment: 7) `.textContent` is better than `.innerHTML` if you want to set just the text content.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple errors in your JS file:

- You are calling the `round_Div_Generator` when you named it `roundDivGenerator`
- You used `roundDiv.class` instead of `roundDiv.className`
- You forgot the `s` in `getElementsByTagName`
- You can directly acces the `document.body`.
- You never defined `roundDivTracker` and `gauballTracker`
- You used `roundDiv.innerHtml` instead of `roundDiv.innerHTML`
- There is no need to use `var roundDivCss = document.getElementByClassName('roundDivClass').style;` since you already have access to the `roundDiv` element. Just use `roundDiv.style`.

Next time, be sure to check your browser console to see the errors in your JS.

```js
const gauballTracker = 'foo';
let roundDivTracker = 0;

function roundDivGenerator() {
  let roundDiv = document.createElement("div");
  roundDiv.id = "roundDiv" + gauballTracker;
  roundDiv.className = "roundDivClass";
  roundDiv.innerHTML = roundDivTracker;
  document.body.appendChild(roundDiv);

  const roundDivCss = roundDiv.style;
  roundDivCss.height = "44px";
  roundDivCss.width = "44px";
  roundDivCss.backgroundColor = "#8ed066";
  roundDivCss.border = "#b0f2e6 3px solid";
  roundDivCss.borderRadius = "22px";
  roundDivCss.textAlign = 'center';

  roundDivTracker++;
}

roundDivGenerator();
roundDivGenerator();
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a bunch of typos. You need to look up the exact names of things you want to use / set before typing them in. Just copy and paste the names of properties and methods from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) if you're unsure. For example, not `innerHtml`, but `innerHTML`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Take a look at what I changed to get the example working, but please just read what the browser console says next time. When your script has an error, it will tell you. (F12 on your keyboard).

```js
var roundDivTracker = 0;
function roundDivGenerator()
{

var roundDiv = document.createElement("div");

  roundDiv.id = "roundDiv" + roundDivTracker;
  roundDiv.class = "roundDivClass";
  roundDiv.innerHTML = roundDivTracker;
  document.body.appendChild(roundDiv);

  // I had to change this for it to work in the code snippet on this site
  //var roundDivCss = document.getElementsByClassName('roundDivClass').style;
  var roundDivCss = roundDiv.style;

    roundDivCss.height = "44px";
    roundDivCss.width = "44px";
    roundDivCss.backgroundColor = "#8ed066";
    roundDivCss.border = "#b0f2e6 3px solid";
    roundDivCss.borderRadius = "22px";

    ++roundDivTracker;
}
roundDivGenerator();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your code:

1. `roundDiv.class = "roundDivClass";` should be: `roundDiv.className = "roundDivClass";`
2. `roundDiv.innerHtml = divTracker;` should be: `roundDiv.innerHTML = divTracker;`
3. `document.getElementByTagName("body")[0]` is wasteful since there is only one `body`. It should be: `document.querySelector("body")`
4. There are several issues with:

   var roundDivCss = document.getElementByClassName('roundDivClass').style;

   a. `getElementsByClassName()` returns a "live" node list that causes the DOM to be researched everytime you access that node list. It can be very wasteful in terms of performance so, if you don't need that "live" behavior, use this instead:

   var roundDivCss = document.querySelectorAll('roundDivClass')

   b. Next, since both `getElementsByClassName()` and `querySelectorAll()` return node lists, you can't access the `style` of that list. You must choose an item from the list and then you can access its `style`.

   c. Accessing the `style` of a DOM element will return an empty string if the element has not had an inline style attached to it (either statically in the HTML or dynamically via JavaScript). If the style has been attached via a CSS class, `style` won't get it. Use `window.getComputedStyle(element).property;` to always get the property, regardless of how it was applied.

   d. This entire line isn't actually necessary in the first place.
5. This code:

   `roundDivCss.height = "44px";
   roundDivCss.width = "44px"; 
   roundDivCss.backgroundColor = "#8ed066";
   roundDivCss.border = "#b0f2e6 3px solid";
   roundDivCss.borderRadius = "22px";`

Should really be turned into a CSS class because all the values are static and then, with one line of code, that class can be applied.

6. Your call to run your function uses a different name than the function itself.
7. Your references to your counter are not the same.

So, here's the reworked code:

```js
var roundDivTracker = 0;

function roundDivGenerator(){

  var roundDiv = document.createElement("div");

  roundDiv.id = "roundDiv" + roundDivTracker;
  roundDiv.innerHTML = roundDivTracker;
  
  // Just one line to attach the class
  roundDiv.classList.add("divClass");

  // Only add the new element once its been completely set up
  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(roundDiv);

  roundDivTracker++;
}

roundDivGenerator();
```

```css
.divClass {
  height : 44px;
  width : 44px;
  background-color : #8ed066;
  border : #b0f2e6 3px solid;
  border-radius : 22px;
  text-align:center;
}
```